# How can I model an M:N relationship using primary keys and foreign keys in place of a bridge-table with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is a pattern I encountered that did not have a clear example within the Sequelize docs. Believe me, I scoured them.

[image]

As you can see in the relations:

The widget_type primary key is a foreign key in the widget and widget_attribute tables.

There are M:1 and 1:N associations between widget & widget_type and widget_type & widget_attribute.

The widget_type relation is used for metadata on the widget's type. So here, it is useful to use that table as the bridge table, instead of creating one where you have a composite key that is the primary key of widget and primary key of widget attribute.

Sequelize does not provide an example of how to do this. And, if you are like me and did not use auto-generated naming for your data model, it becomes all the more confusing to model associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WidgetAttribute.belongsToMany(Widget, { as: "attributes", through: WidgetType, uniqueKey: 'widget_type', foreignKey: 'widget_type', otherKey: 'widget_type' });
Widget.belongsToMany(WidgetAttribute, { as: "widgets", through: WidgetType, uniqueKey: 'widget_type', foreignKey: 'widget_type', otherKey: 'widget_type' });

WidgetType.hasMany(WidgetAttribute, { sourceKey: 'widget_type', foreignKey: 'widget_type' });
WidgetType.hasMany(Widget, { sourceKey: 'widget_type', foreignKey: 'widget_type' });

Widget.belongsTo(WidgetType, { foreignKey: 'widget_type', targetKey: 'widget_type' });
WidgetAttribute.belongsTo(WidgetType, { foreignKey: 'widget_type', targetKey: 'widget_type' });
```

You can create the M:N association as described above using these Sequelize assocations between models. Remember:

- In WidgetAttribute, widget_type is a foreign key attribute.
- In Widget, widget_type is a foreign key attribute.
- In WidgetType, widget_type is a primary key.